# Symfony Chain Multiple Authentication Listeners

Tags: symfony, authentication, listener

I have implemented custom authentication, with the whole shebang (custom Token, Listener, Factory, Provider) which I will call as a whole **WebserviceAuthentication**.

This, as the name implies, authenticates with a custom webservice, receives a few API tokens, etc. etc. and is working fine by itself.

I now want use the **FOSUserBundle** to authenticate. I have enabled it in my security.yml file, and the cleaned up version is below. The entire point is to authenticate locally, and if that fails, then authenticate with the webservice.

Both of my providers use different tokens. My token for **WebserviceAuthentication** has a couple of custom attributes, and is not the same as the **UsernamePasswordToken** that FOSUserBundle uses.

My question is, how do I use one authentication mechanism first, and then go onto the second one? When I enable it as it is now, I can authenticate with FOSUserBundle Users, but I can't authenticate with my webservice users.

In the current state, if the local authentication fails, it tries to invoke the second WebserviceAuthentication provider. However, it `supports()` a different a token, which means that it's skipped and never called.

Any advice on how to do this? Is there any way to chain authentication listeners to try the FOSUser listener first, and then try the Webservice? The reason I am thinking Listeners is because that's where the **Token** is initially created. Any advice is appreciated.

**security.yml**

```
 providers:
        #chain_provider:
        #  chain:
        #    providers: [ws_provider, fos_userbundle]
        fos_userbundle:
          id: fos_user.user_provider.username
        ws_provider:
          id: ws.user_provider 
 firewalls:
        ws_secured:
            pattern:   ^/
            logout:
              path:   /logout
              target: /
              success_handler: bo.logout.success.handler
            anonymous: true
            wslogin:
              check_path: /login_check
              login_path: /login
              provider: ws_provider
              default_target_path: /
              success_handler: some.success.handler
            form_login:
              provider: fos_userbundle
              csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
              failure_handler: some.failure.handler
              success_handler: some.success.handler
```

Comment: Have you tried to chain providers not authentication handlers ?http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/multiple_user_providers.html

Comment: I have tried chaining providers as seen in the security.yml (which is commented out). The problem I'm facing with that is each provider supports a different token, so when the listener calls the second provider, it doesn't support the token that the first listener creates.

Comment: yes Now I see the problem , you can have a look at this documentation if you are using `2.4` version. http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-customize-the-security-features-with-ease#using-several-authenticators-in-a-firewall , It may help you

Comment: We're slow over here, still on 2.3. I'll look into it, thanks.

Comment: No luck with that link related to 2.4. Still looking into this...

Comment: quick question , it may seem dump but anyway , does your custom token class extend `AbstractToken` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78220/discussion-between-faisal-m-and-zizoujab).